Navigation no map and odom
I'm trying to do navigation in Ros, but when I run the navigation launch file with the map obtained through slam, it doesn't work properly. When I check the tf tree, the map and odom do not exist as shown below. 
I thought that amcl creates map and odom, but I don't know what the problem is. The following is part of my amcl launch file and part of navigation launch file. If anyone know the cause of the problem, can anyone tell me the cause and solution?



Please do not post images of Terminal output. Instead, copy/paste the actual text and format it.

AMCL does map->odom transform. You also need odom->baselink transform. Odom to baselink can be calculated using IMU or whell encoder data. As i see from you launch files you have an IMU sensor. You can use robot_localization package to make odom transformation.

Your assumption that amcl "creates" the map TF frame is not correct. You should run a map_server node and configure it to publish to the /map ros topic.
